# ios expandable/collapsable view inside scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am building a scrollview dynamically. Now in that scrollview , I would be giving user an option to "view more" maybe an icon sort of. On click of this icon the scrollview should show some data below the icon and on "view less" should collapse it.

Is it possible to have this kind of functionality ? I am not sure since the elements which are below the "view name" icon should make space so that the details can be show and vice versa.

Any idea if any such functionality was developed in any such app or should I use some other view widget ?

Thanks.

Comment: If possible I would use a table view or even better a collection view for that. But it's also possible with a scroll view. In this case I would define constrains and alter those when the user clicks the more button.

Comment: Why not you try to show your images in UITableView or UICollectionView? Both are providing you re-usability of cells or row that can be much more easy for memory management.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer , could not find a good example of doing this in collectionview but TableView can be used. Let me try if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use auto layout it's pretty straightforward:

- change frame width and height of your `UIScrollView` if needed
- add more info or view in `UIScrollView`
- set `UIScrollView` `contentSize` property with new size of content

In case you using auto layout you should change auto layout constraint appropriately. Good practice is add all your `UIScrollView` subview in one content view (simple `UIView`) and configure all constraint for this content view. 
For tips how to configure auto layout constraint take a look in official documentation: [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/)

[This book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html) has very good explanation of auto layout too.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but if I add more views in between in a scrollview, the views below need to also move down right ? So I would be doing all those rendering of views again based on new position right ? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yeah, that's sad, but you must recalculate all the position below the view you want to insert. Or if you're using auto layout you can just align every next view based on previous one, so when you want to insert new one in between you just need to change few constraints(for view below and under new view).
Of course you can use `UITableView` to achieve the same behavior easily